# Get an array of dates using Carbon in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm a beginner in Laravel/PHP, and I'm using the Carbon class to manage dates.
I need to get an array of datetime by month, from the beginning of the previous year till this month, the output should be as follow :

```
$dates = [
    '2016-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-02-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-03-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-04-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-05-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-06-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-07-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-08-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-09-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-10-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-11-01 00:00:00',
    '2016-12-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-01-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-02-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-03-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-04-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-05-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-06-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-07-01 00:00:00',
    '2017-08-01 00:00:00',
];
```

I can't figure out how to do this, thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have already the dates and you have to order them, or you what to generate dates as every first of the month in several years (as the answer from @Arthur Samarcos)?

Comment: I need to generate the array of dates, beginning from the previous year (so if we're in 2020, the previous year should be 2019) till the current month, so the last date should be `2017-08-01 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function dates()
{
    $start = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYear()->startOfYear();
    $months_to_render = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInMonths($start);

    $dates = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $months_to_render; $i++) {
        $dates[] = $start->toDateTimeString();
        $start->addMonth();
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but the dates should stop at the current month, which is in this case `august 2017`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that requirement. @dwix

Comment: Thank you, it is working, but it begins from `2016-02-01` instead of `2016-01-01` .